# How to fetch fields from request in Node.js using express framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, body-parser

I am writing a Node.js script and having problems with integration of a "login" form.  I can do it using a static HTML page, however using a dynamic ".ejs" page is causing problems...my form fields are reported as "undefined".

```
var helmet = require('helmet');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
//var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
//var csurf = require('csurf');
//Use Express module
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var io = require("socket.io");  //web socket external module
var easyrtc = require("easyrtc");  //EasyRTC external module

app.use(helmet());

//Statically serve files in these directories
app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + '/easyrtc/js'));
app.use("/images", express.static(__dirname + '/easyrtc/images'));
app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + '/easyrtc/css'));

//For my homepage  
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')  //set the view engine to ejs

app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'));
app.use("/img", express.static(__dirname + '/public/img'));

//Needed to parse form data 
app.use(bodyParser()); 

//var csrfProtection = csurf({ cookie: true });  
//parse cookies...we need this because "cookie" is true in csrfProtection
//app.use(cookieParser());

//global variables 
var loggedIn = false,
    password = 'password';  
var title = 'This is a heading';
var message = 'Steve is NOT available';
var presenter = 'Username'
var passport = 'Password'    


//Temporary home page
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

var site = req.hostname;  //example returns "localhost"
var splits = site.split(".");  //"split" on "periods"

console.log("site is: " + site);
console.log("first split is: " + splits[0]);
console.log("second split is: " + splits[1]);

if (loggedIn == true) {
res.render('index', {title: 'available', message: 'Steve is available...'});
console.log("homepage -logged in");
}
else {
console.log("homepage -not logged in");
  res.render('login', {
    usr: {},
    pword: {},
    data: {},
    errors: {}//,
//        csrfToken: req.csrfToken()
  });
 }
});

//Respond to POST from login form
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
console.log('post to /login');

var usr_STR = String(req.body.usr)
var pass_STR = String(req.body.pword)
console.log("req.body.usr: " + req.body.usr + " req.body.pword: " + req.body.pword);
console.log("usr_STR: " + usr_STR + " pass_STR: " + pass_STR);

if (loggedIn == true) {
    res.send("Already logged in.");
}
else {
    console.log("Posted data:" + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    console.log("req.body.pw:" + req.body.pw);
    console.log("req.body.pword:" + req.body.pword);
    console.log("req.body.usr:" + req.body.usr);
    if (req.body.pword == password) {
        loggedIn = true;
        res.send("You are logged in.");
        console.log("Logged in");

        // Start EasyRTC server
        var easyrtcServer = easyrtc.listen(app, socketServer);

    }
    else {

        res.render('login', {
          data: req.body,  //{ presenter, passport }
          errors: {
            presenter: {
            msg: 'Your username does not look right'
            },
            passport: {
            msg: 'Your password does not look right'
            }
          }//,
//              csrfToken: req.csrfToken()
        });

    }
 }
});

//Error Handling
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!")
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
console.error(err.stack)
res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
});


// Start server on port 8080
var webServer = app.listen(8080);
console.log('Listening on port ' + 80);

// Start Socket.io so it attaches itself to Express server
var socketServer = io.listen(webServer);
```

I am seeing my console report back the following to me:

```
Posted data:{}

req.body.pword:undefined

req.body.usr:undefined
```

I am still somewhat new to working with Node.Js and obviously I'm having some confusion about how to pass the parameters from my (.ejs) form to my route handler within the req.body ...any advice would be GREATLY appreciated, I'm really struggling trying to figure this out.  Thank you in advance.  Regards.

NOTE:  As can be seen in my code, I removed the references to "csurf" and "cookieparser" since in my earlier runs this information WAS returned within the "req.body"...so I thought they were somehow interfering...however it seems there is something else going on.

Here is the associated HTML for the login form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="form-header">
  <% if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) { %>
  <h2>Login Form</h2>
  <% } else { %>
  <h2 class="errors-heading">Oops, please correct the following:</h2>
  <ul class="errors-list">
   <% Object.values(errors).forEach(error => { %>
    <li><%= error.msg %></li>
   <% }) %>
   </ul>
   <% } %>
</div>


<form method="post" action="/login" novalidate>
<div class="imgcontainer">
<img src="img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
</div>

<div class="container">
<label for="usr"><b>Username</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder=<%= data.presenter %> name="usr" required>

<% if (errors.presenter) { %>
  <div class="error"><%= errors.presenter.msg %></div>
<% } %>

<label for="pword"><b>Password</b></label>
<input type="password" placeholder=<%= data.passport %> name="pword" required>

<% if (errors.passport) { %>
  <div class="error"><%= errors.passport.msg %></div>
<% } %>

<button type="submit">Login</button>

</div>

<div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
<button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
<span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `body-parser`, just importing it won't work out.
Also checkout [body-parser docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

```
// configure the app to use bodyParser()

// parse urlencoded data type as JSON
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

// parse various different custom JSON types as JSON
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));

// parse some custom thing into a Buffer
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/vnd.custom-type' }));

// parse an HTML body into a string
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'text/html' }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I thought I was using it...my line here:  "//Needed to parse form data 
app.use(bodyParser()); ".   ...no?

Comment: Hello...I was unable to make your solution work for me...I noticed no difference in behaviour.  After 2 days of pounding my head against the wall and basically beginning from scratch I was able to work out my problem(s)...I thank you for your response and time anyway...I appreciate the effort.